# $.post Jquery send array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have problem with send array in $.post to php.
var_dump result is "NULL"
JSON.stringify doesn't work..

**JQUERY**

```
var photobox = []; 

photobox.push(e.target.result); 

$.post("../modules/upload.php",{"images[]" : photobox, count : sum},
                   function(data)
                    {
                        $('.list').prepend(data);
                    }).done(function() {
    $('#files').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.file-search').html("Szukaj...");
    $(".img-thumbnail").removeClass("first");
    $(".img-thumbnail").first().addClass("first");
```

> e.target.result is base64 code

**PHP**

```
$images = $_POST['images'];
var_dump($images);
```

Comment: Refer to my answer, it should do what you are asking for.

Comment: Are you trying to upload images?

Comment: Yes, images save in base64.

Answer (score 0):

You can send arrays like this:

```
$.post('/thepage.php', {'NameOfKey': variableName});
```

The above code will allow VariableName to be an Array.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but this code still doesn't work :/

Comment: Try just posting photobox array, and then see what happens, echo out what is posted. Turn the script into smaller pieces to identify what is wrong.

Comment: Echo return "Array".
If i want use print_r this array do value result is `ArrayArray ( [0] => [] )`
But if insert 'photobox' in the console.log do result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to encode to JSON on your client, but when on your server (PHP) convert it back to an array by using json_decode:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I try this way, but dont have result. json_decode return empty values - "[]"